# Is it possible to remove the binary values that prefix the output of teradata fexp?

Tags: teradata

I am trying to run teradata `fexp` with a simple sql script.

The select output column is a string expression and as such results in 2 extra length indicator bytes at the start of each row output.

I have searched for solutions online to the problem. I would like to avoid having to post-process if possible.

There is a thread suggesting the possibility of using an OUTMOD. I don't know what that is.
https://forums.teradata.com/forum/tools/fastexport-remove-binaryindicator-values-in-outmod
http://teradataforum.com/teradata/20100726_155313.htm

And yet another thread suggests casting to a fixed width string type but this would result in padding which I'd like to avoid.
https://forums.teradata.com/forum/tools/fexp-data-doubt

The desired output is actually a delimited plain text file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Don't use legacy FastExport, switch to TPT Export, then it's a simple `FORMAT DELIMITED`

Comment: is it possible to install tpt even without admin priveleges? If so where can I get binary for redhat?